# jQuery $.each iterating through firebase array twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am trying to use jQuery with firebase on the web and am building a quick table of users and tickets. The users and tickets are displaying properly, however they are iterated over twice, in that the table contains the same users and tickets twice. I am not sure what is happening.`

```
     var users = ["Nick","Peter"];
     var rows = "";
     var number = 0;

 //Sync all changes
 dbRefAllUsers.on('value', function(snap) {

     console.log("#Run",number+1);

     jQuery.each(users, function(index,name){
         console.log(name);
         rows += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + snap.child(name).child("tickets").val() + "</td></tr>";
         console.log(rows);
         });

     $(rows).appendTo("#ticketTable tbody");

     return head.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);

 });`
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1 id="head"></h1>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.7/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>

    <table id="ticketTable" style="font-size:18px;">
        <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>Users</th>
            <th>Tickets</th>
        </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see two `"#Run..."` entries in your console? Look for a number to the left of the console line. Alternatively, change your code to `console.log('#Run', ++number)`

Comment: No there is only a single console log for Run, ("Run# 1"). Similarly the console logs Nick and Peter (name) once, and rows for each of them.